# How do you use segmented picker to change chart axis in React Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, graph, charts, expo

[image]

I want to do something similar to this, in which I use the segmented picker to change the scale of the graphs. Right now, I have the segmented picker, but I'd like to use this to change the graph axis to correspond with day, week, month, and year. Is there any existing libraries that can do this? Or can I create a custom chart that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is when the segment control is changed, update the state containing the data for each graph, so when you go from Day to Month, the data changes accordingly. You can also have independent components containing each graph for each segmented control value, though this would just be the same code with different data in each.

While there is no exact library to use, there are ones that could be made to look similar to it with some modifications, take a look at [react-native-pure-chart](https://github.com/oksktank/react-native-pure-chart).